# Understanding WeightedKappaLoss using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, cohen-kappa, ordinal-classification

I'm using Keras to try to predict a vector of scores (0-1) using a sequence of events.

For example, **X** is a sequence of 3 vectors comprised of 6 features each, while **y** is a vector of 3 scores:

```
X
[
  [1,2,3,4,5,6], <--- dummy data
  [1,2,3,4,5,6],
  [1,2,3,4,5,6]
]

y
[0.34 ,0.12 ,0.46] <--- dummy data
```

I want to adress the problem as ordinal classification, so if the actual values are `[0.5,0.5,0.5]` the prediction `[0.49,0.49,0.49]` is better then `[0.3,0.3,0.3]`. My Original solution, was to use `sigmoid` activation on my last layer and `mse` as the loss function, so the output is ranged between 0-1 for each of the output neurons:

```
def get_model(num_samples, num_features, output_size):
    opt = Adam()
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(LSTM(config['lstm_neurons'], activation=config['lstm_activation'], input_shape=(num_samples, num_features)))
    model.add(Dropout(config['dropout_rate']))

    for layer in config['dense_layers']:
      model.add(Dense(layer['neurons'], activation=layer['activation']))

    model.add(Dense(output_size, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

    return model
```

My Goal is to understand the usage of **WeightedKappaLoss** and to implement it on my actual data. I've created **[this Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dJLzdqWLBJDvnExTAv1Ty1kk9ccReluR?usp=sharing)** to fiddle around with the idea.  In the Colab, my data is a sequence shaped `(5000,3,3)` and my targets shape is `(5000, 4)` representing 1 of 4 possible classes.

I want the model to understand that it needs to trim the floating point of the X in order to predict the right y class:

```
[[3.49877793, 3.65873511, 3.20218196],
 [3.20258153, 3.7578669 , 3.83365481],
 [3.9579924 , 3.41765455, 3.89652426]], ----> y is 3 [0,0,1,0]

[[1.74290875, 1.41573056, 1.31195701],
 [1.89952004, 1.95459796, 1.93148095],
 [1.18668981, 1.98982041, 1.89025326]], ----> y is 1 [1,0,0,0]
```

New model code:

```
def get_model(num_samples, num_features, output_size):
    opt = Adam(learning_rate=config['learning_rate'])
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(LSTM(config['lstm_neurons'], activation=config['lstm_activation'], input_shape=(num_samples, num_features)))
    model.add(Dropout(config['dropout_rate']))

    for layer in config['dense_layers']:
      model.add(Dense(layer['neurons'], activation=layer['activation']))

    model.add(Dense(output_size, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss=tfa.losses.WeightedKappaLoss(num_classes=4), optimizer=opt, metrics=[tfa.metrics.CohenKappa(num_classes=4)])

    return model
```

When fitting the model I can see the following metrics on TensorBoard:
[image][image]

I'm not sure about the following points and would appreciate clarification:

- Am I using it right?
- In my original problem, I'm predicting 3 scores, as opposed of the Colab example, where I'm predicting only 1. If I'm using WeightedKappaLoss, does it mean I'll need to convert each of the scores to a vector of 100 one-hot encoding?
- Is there a way to use the WeightedKappaLoss on the original floating point scores without converting to a classification problem?

Comment: To make sure I understand your original problem (because you have gave multiple descriptions with some inconsistencies), let me give a description: basically, in the problem you are working on, each input sample is a timeseries of shape `(seq_len, seq_features)` and you are interested to predict a score for each timestep of the input sample (an output of shape `(seq_len,)`); however, the scores themselves are not important to you, and your main concern is to find the correct order (or ranking) of the timesteps in *each input sample*. **Is that a correct description, or have I missed a point?**

Comment: If you're original task is to "to predict a vector of scores (0-1)", why do you want to address it as an ordinal classification and not regression, like using sigmoid as you suggested? Is it because you did not obtain acceptable results with regression/sigmoid framework?

Comment: @today thank you for your reply, what I'm trying to predict is a single time stamp in the future. I.E let's say that the sequence is of 100 timestamps, I want to use the first 50 to predict the last one (timestamp 100)

Comment: @SaTa thank you for your reply, I just want to see if I can attack the problem from a different angle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let we separate the goal to two sub-goals, we walk through the **purpose**, **concept**, **mathematical details** of `Weighted Kappa` first, after that we summarize the things to note when we try to use `WeightedKappaLoss` in tensorflow

PS: you can skip the understand part if you only care about usage

---

## Weighted Kappa detailed explanation

Since the **Weighted Kappa** can be see as **Cohen's kappa + weights**, so we need to understand the **Cohen's kappa** first

### Example of Cohen's kappa

Suppose we have two classifier (A and B) trying to classify 50 statements into two categories (True and False), the way they classify those statements wrt each other in a contingency table:

```
         B
         True False
A True   20   5     25 statements A think is true
  False  10   15    25 statements A think is false
         30 statements B think is true
              20 statements B think is false
```

Now suppose we want know: **How reliable the prediction A and B made?**

What we can do is simply take the percentage of classified statements which A and B agree with each other, i.e **proportion of observed agreement** denote as `Po`, so:

```
Po = (20 + 15) / 50 = 0.7
```

But this is problematic, because there have probability that A and B agree with each other by random chance, i.e **proportion of expected chance agreement** denote as `Pe`, if we use observed percentage as expect probability, then:

```
Pe = (probability statement A think is true) * (probability statement B think is true) +
     (probability statement A think is false) * (probability statement B think is false) 
   = (25 / 50) * (30 / 50) + 
     (25 / 50) * (20 / 50)
   = 0.5
```

**Cohen's kappa coefficient** denote as `K` that incorporate `Po` and `Pe` to give us more robust prediction about reliability of prediction A and B made:

[image]

```
K = (Po - Pe) / (1 - Pe) = 1 - (1 - Po) / (1 - Pe) = 1 - (1 - 0.7) / (1 - 0.5) = 0.4
```

We can see the more A and B are agree with each other (`Po` higher) and less they agree because of chance (`Pe` lower), the more **Cohen's kappa** "think" the result is reliable

Now assume A is the labels (ground truth) of statements, then `K` is telling us how reliable the B's prediction are, i.e how much prediction agree with labels when take random chance into consideration

### Weights for Cohen's kappa

We define the contingency table with `m` classes formally:

```
                                    classifier 2
                       class.1  class.2  class... class.k  Sum over row
               class.1   n11      n12      ...      n1k      n1+  
               class.2   n21      n22      ...      n2k      n2+  
classifier 1   class...  ...      ...      ...      ...      ...  
               class.k   nk1      nk2      ...      nkk      nk+  
       Sum over column   n+1      n+2      ...      n+k      N   # total sum of all table cells
```

The table cells contain the counts of cross-classified categories denote as `nij`, `i,j` for row and column index respectively

Consider those `k` ordinal classes are separate from two categorical classes, e.g separate `1, 0` into five classes `1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0` which have a smooth ordered transition, we cannot say the classes are independent except the first and last class, e.g `very good, good, normal, bad, very bad`, the `very good` and `good` are not independent and the `good` should closer to `bad` than to `very bad`

Since the adjacent classes are interdependent then in order to calculate the quantity related to agreement we need define this dependency, i.e **Weights** denote as `Wij`, it assigned to each cell in the contingency table, value of weight (within range [0, 1]) depend on how close two classes are

Now let's look at `Po` and `Pe` formula in **Weighted Kappa**:

[image]

And `Po` and `Pe` formula in **Cohen's kappa**:

[image]

We can see `Po` and `Pe` formula in **Cohen's kappa** is special case of formula in **Weighted Kappa**, where `weight = 1` assigned to all diagonal cells and weight = 0 elsewhere, when we calculate `K` (Cohen's kappa coefficient) using `Po` and `Pe` formula in **Weighted Kappa** we also take dependency between adjacent classes into consideration

Here are two commonly used weighting system:

1. Linear weight:

[image]

2. Quadratic weight:

[image]

Where, `|i-j|` is the distance between classes and `k` is the number of classes

### Weighted Kappa Loss

This loss is use in case we mentioned before where one classifier is the labels, and the purpose of this loss is to make the model's (another classifier) prediction as reliable as possible, i.e encourage model to make more prediction agree with labels while make less random guess when take dependency between adjacent classes into consideration

The formula of **Weighted Kappa Loss** given by:

[image]

It just take formula of negative **Cohen's kappa coefficient** and get rid of constant `-1` then apply **natural logarithm** on it, where `dij = |i-j|` for **Linear weight**, `dij = (|i-j|)^2` for **Quadratic weight**

Following is the source code of **Weighted Kappa Loss** written with tensroflow, as you can see it just implement the formula of **Weighted Kappa Loss** above:

```
import warnings
from typing import Optional

import tensorflow as tf
from typeguard import typechecked

from tensorflow_addons.utils.types import Number

class WeightedKappaLoss(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    @typechecked
    def __init__(
        self,
        num_classes: int,
        weightage: Optional[str] = "quadratic",
        name: Optional[str] = "cohen_kappa_loss",
        epsilon: Optional[Number] = 1e-6,
        dtype: Optional[tf.DType] = tf.float32,
        reduction: str = tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE,
    ):
        super().__init__(name=name, reduction=reduction)
        warnings.warn(
            "The data type for `WeightedKappaLoss` defaults to "
            "`tf.keras.backend.floatx()`."
            "The argument `dtype` will be removed in Addons `0.12`.",
            DeprecationWarning,
        )
        if weightage not in ("linear", "quadratic"):
            raise ValueError("Unknown kappa weighting type.")

        self.weightage = weightage
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.epsilon = epsilon or tf.keras.backend.epsilon()
        label_vec = tf.range(num_classes, dtype=tf.keras.backend.floatx())
        self.row_label_vec = tf.reshape(label_vec, [1, num_classes])
        self.col_label_vec = tf.reshape(label_vec, [num_classes, 1])
        col_mat = tf.tile(self.col_label_vec, [1, num_classes])
        row_mat = tf.tile(self.row_label_vec, [num_classes, 1])
        if weightage == "linear":
            self.weight_mat = tf.abs(col_mat - row_mat)
        else:
            self.weight_mat = (col_mat - row_mat) ** 2

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=self.col_label_vec.dtype)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, dtype=self.weight_mat.dtype)
        batch_size = tf.shape(y_true)[0]
        cat_labels = tf.matmul(y_true, self.col_label_vec)
        cat_label_mat = tf.tile(cat_labels, [1, self.num_classes])
        row_label_mat = tf.tile(self.row_label_vec, [batch_size, 1])
        if self.weightage == "linear":
            weight = tf.abs(cat_label_mat - row_label_mat)
        else:
            weight = (cat_label_mat - row_label_mat) ** 2
        numerator = tf.reduce_sum(weight * y_pred)
        label_dist = tf.reduce_sum(y_true, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        pred_dist = tf.reduce_sum(y_pred, axis=0, keepdims=True)
        w_pred_dist = tf.matmul(self.weight_mat, pred_dist, transpose_b=True)
        denominator = tf.reduce_sum(tf.matmul(label_dist, w_pred_dist))
        denominator /= tf.cast(batch_size, dtype=denominator.dtype)
        loss = tf.math.divide_no_nan(numerator, denominator)
        return tf.math.log(loss + self.epsilon)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            "num_classes": self.num_classes,
            "weightage": self.weightage,
            "epsilon": self.epsilon,
        }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config, **config}
```

---

## Usage of Weighted Kappa Loss

We can using **Weighted Kappa Loss** whenever we can form our problem to **Ordinal Classification Problems**, i.e the classes form a smooth ordered transition and adjacent classes are interdependent, like ranking something with `very good, good, normal, bad, very bad`, and the output of the model should be like `Softmax` results

We cannot using **Weighted Kappa Loss** when we try to predict the vector of scores (0-1) even if they can sum to `1`, since the **Weights** in each elements of vector is different and this loss not ask how different is the value by subtract, but ask how many are the number by multiplication, e.g:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_addons.losses import WeightedKappaLoss

y_true = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1], [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1],
                      [0.8, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1], [0.01, 0.09, 0.1, 0.8]])
y_pred_0 = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.1], [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1],
                      [0.8, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1], [0.01, 0.09, 0.1, 0.8]])
y_pred_1 = tf.constant([[0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 0.0], [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1],
                      [0.8, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1], [0.01, 0.09, 0.1, 0.8]])

kappa_loss = WeightedKappaLoss(weightage='linear', num_classes=4)
loss_0 = kappa_loss(y_true, y_pred_0)
loss_1 = kappa_loss(y_true, y_pred_1)
print('Loss_0: {}, loss_1: {}'.format(loss_0.numpy(), loss_1.numpy()))
```

Outputs:

```
# y_pred_0 equal to y_true yet loss_1 is smaller than loss_0
Loss_0: -0.7053321599960327, loss_1: -0.8015820980072021
```

Your code in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dJLzdqWLBJDvnExTAv1Ty1kk9ccReluR?usp=sharing) is working correctly in the context of **Ordinal Classification Problems**, since the function you form `X->Y` is very simple (int of X is Y index + 1), so the model learn it fairly quick and accurate, as we can see `K` (Cohen's kappa coefficient) up to `1.0` and Weighted Kappa Loss drop below `-13.0` (which in practice usually is minimal we can expect)

In summary, you can using **Weighted Kappa Loss** unless you can form your problem to **Ordinal Classification Problems** which have labels in one-hot fashion, if you can and trying to solve the LTR (Learning to rank) problems, then you can check [this tutorial of implement ListNet](https://theiconic.tech/learning-to-rank-is-good-for-your-ml-career-part-2-lets-implement-listnet-11af69d1704) and [this tutorial of tensorflow_ranking](https://quantdare.com/learning-to-rank-with-tensorflow/) for better result, otherwise you shouldn't using **Weighted Kappa Loss**, if you can only form your problem to **Regression Problems**, then you should do the same as your original solution

---

## Reference:

[Cohen's kappa on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa)

[Weighted Kappa in R: For Two Ordinal Variables](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/weighted-kappa-in-r-for-two-ordinal-variables/)

[source code of WeightedKappaLoss in tensroflow-addons](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.11.2/tensorflow_addons/losses/kappa_loss.py)

[Documentation of tfa.losses.WeightedKappaLoss](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/WeightedKappaLoss)

[Difference between categorical, ordinal and numerical variables](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/what-is-the-difference-between-categorical-ordinal-and-numerical-variables/)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that detailed answer, kudos for that, well deserved the bounty!

Comment: Glad to write this one and thank you for your approval, I also learn few things while writing it, have a good day : )